# LaTeX Error: Command \footref already defined. in TeX Live 2021

Tags: texlive, texlive-2021

On Arch Linux with LuaHBTeX v1.13.2 / TeX Live 2021, I suddenly get an error message on compile. My questions are:

- Why this high line number "l.6171" – my .tex file only has 1228 lines?
- What does the error mean and to which manual's page 192 does it refer to? `\footref` does not appear in my .tex file.
- Is it a bug in the TeX distro?

```
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'bedienungsanleitung_final_de.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "bedienungsanleitung_final_de.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./bedienungsanleitung_final_de.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2019/12/23 v3.28 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \InputIfFileExists   has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

))) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Command \footref already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6171 }
      
?
```

Comment: footref is now in latex. KOMA has been adapted for this but your version is too old. The line number refers to scrartcl.cls

Comment: `koma-script` is not an Arch package anymore but the old version was still installed. After uninstalling it, everything works again. Thank you!

Comment: the log fragment shows the line number in the error refers to /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls not to your document line number (see the matching `(..)` )